# Update values in one object update second object values ASP.Net identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am fetching this 2 object based on id, Id is same

```
var oldeUserExist = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserData.Id ?? null);
var userExist = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserData.Id ?? null);
```

what is the issue is

->Consider oldeUserExist.phonenumber is null

-> If I update phone number value in a userExist  object it updates that phone number value in the oldeUserExist object also that cause issue

My question is FindByIdAsync is giving copy by reference object? if yes then what should we do for avoiding this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just create a clone of the User object with the following code:

```
public static T Clone<T>(T toClone) where T : class
{
        string tmp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toClone,Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
        });
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(tmp);
}
```

This way the 2 objects wont be referenced with each other.